# drawing on UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing iPhone application and I have taken UIView and I want to draw particular region on view on user touchMove event. So please can anybody suggest to me how to do it means how to implement the touchMove event so it can draw region concurrently with user touchMove.

Comment: can you show us what code you have/any attempts youve made?

Comment: I tried with this Code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249683/how-to-draw-polygons-with-cgpath

Comment: I also tried this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669490/how-to-draw-line-on-touch-event but still its not working.please help me

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is:

1. Create subclass of `UIView`.
2. Implement all the touch methods like
   `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:`, etc.
3. Use `drawRect:`,
   `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and `UIBezierPath` to draw
   image based on touch locations.

There are many tutorials on the internet. I find this one quite good: [Advanced Freehand Drawing Techniques](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-advanced-freehand-drawing-techniques--mobile-15602)

[image]

Comment: Thanks As I am new in iOS programming So can I draw without using UIImage additional on simple UIView.

Comment: @Ashok, implementing drawing is not a trivial task. That's why I recommend you following a tutorial that explains step by step what you should do.